# jQuery issue with fade actions doubling

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bear with me, this might take a little explanation. I apologize in advance if I don't quite explain it clearly.

I am building a jQuery Slider (wordpress plugin) for a client project and involves the following functionality:

- Groups of slides are loaded a group at a time
- Play/Pause
- Next Slide/ Previous Slide
- Next Group/ Previous Group
- Autoplay

It is slightly different in the fact that it has 'groups' of slides with only one Title/Description combo. You then navigate not only between the different slides of each group, but also the groups themselves.

**My problem is** that after I pause the autorun for the slideshow and resume it again, the next_slide() action is taken twice (fades out/fades in fades out/fades in), almost as if the setTimeout() has doubled up on itself.

**Edit**: Now it appears to be occurring whenever the next_slide() action is taken, and not only after play/pause as I had previously thought. The slide number doesn't advance, but rather fades the same image twice. I have had it stack the same image upwards to 4 times, and have no idea why. My apologies for the confusion.

Could it be that because my .live('click') event is simply calling next_slide() that it is stacking up?

**NOTE** - I cleared away some code for readability such as .click events for triggering the functions with the frontend buttons and the set_information function. As far as I can tell, they are not the source of my problems.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. What would be causing the double action of the next_slide() function? Feel free to also critique my code in other aspects, I know that it is far from perfect:

```
function build_slideshow(grouplist){

    var group_array = jQuery.parseJSON(grouplist); // parse AJAX returned JSON

    var n = 0; //group counter
    var x = 0; //slide counter
    var length = group_array.length - 1; //amount of groups
    var count; // number of slides in group
    var size; // size of window (to pull proper image sizes)
    var autorun = null;

    window_size(); // set size variable for later use
    slideshow_init(); //start the slideshow


    /* ------- FUNCTIONS  -------- */

    /*
    checks window.width for AJAX call
    */

    function window_size(){     
        window_size = $j(window).width();

        switch(true){
            case(window_size > 980):
            size = 'large';
            break;

            case(window_size > 480 && window_size < 980):
            size = 'med';
            break;

            case(window_size < 480):
            size = 'small';
            break;
       }
    }

    function slideshow_init(){
        set_information(); //places Title, Desc, and Slider nav buttons
        get_slides(group_array[n].id); //builds slideshow for group
    }




    function get_slides(group_id){

        $j.post(myAjax.ajaxurl, {action:"get_slides_list", groupid:group_id, size:size}, function(result){

            slide_data = jQuery.parseJSON(result); 
            count = slide_data.length;
            if(autorun) clearTimeout(autorun); //resets the setTimeout from previous group
            x = 0; //resets the counter from previous group

           $j('.slideshow div').hide();
           $j('.slideshow div').html(slide_data[x]).fadeIn(700); //loads first slide

           if(play == true){ //possible that user paused the slideshow last group
               setTimeout(slideshow_autorun, 6000); //autoruns if not
           }
        });
     }


    function next_slide(){
        x++;

        (x == count) ? x = 0 : x = x; //loops to front if last slide

       $j('.slideshow div').fadeOut( 700 ,  function() {
       $j(this).html(slide_data[x]);
       }).fadeIn(700);
    }

    function previous_slide(){
        x--;

        (x <  0) ? x = (count - 1) : x = x; // loops to back if first slide

        $j('.slideshow div').fadeOut( 700 ,  function() {
        $j(this).html(slide_data[x]);
        }).fadeIn(700);
    }

    function next_group(){
        n++;

        (n > length) ? n = 0 : n = n; //loops to front if last group
        slideshow_init();
    }

    function previous_group(){
        n--;

        (n < 0) ? n = length : n = n; //loops to back if first group
        slideshow_init();
    }

    function play_slideshow(){
         play = true;

         slideshow_autorun();
    } 

    function pause_slideshow(){
        if(autorun) clearTimeout(autorun);

        play = false;    
    }

    function slideshow_autorun(){
        if(play == true){
        next_slide();

        autorun = setTimeout(slideshow_autorun, 6000);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the 'how', but I still am unsure as to the 'why'.

The next_slide() function was the problem:

```
function next_slide(){
   x++;

    (x == count) ? x = 0 : x = x;

   $j('.slideshow div').fadeOut( 700 ,  function() {
    $j(this).html(slide_data[x]);
   }).fadeIn(700);

}
```

What I changed it to, which appeared to fix the problem:

```
function next_slide(){
   x++;

    (x == count) ? x = 0 : x = x;

   $j('.slideshow div').fadeOut( 700 ,  function() {
    $j(this).html(slide_data[x]).fadeIn(700);
   });

}
```

By moving the .fadeIn inside the function, it somehow ensured that it wouldn't double up. Anyone have an explanation?  I also auto-paused the autorun on the slideshow when the button was pressed to ensure that it wouldn't get ugly, which I'm sure users won't mind if they are wanting to go their own speed anyways.